# SQL simplify table of many columns into less column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table shown like this :

```
PO_ID | PO_TYPE | PO_STAT | MR_ID | MR_TYPE | MR_STAT | IN_ID | IN_TYPE | IN_STAT
  1   |   A1    |   CO    |   1   |   B1    |   DR    |   1   |   C1    |  CO
  2   |   A1    |   CO    |   2   |   B2    |   CO    |   2   |   C1    |  CO
```

I'd like to simplify this table to become like this :

```
ID   |  TYPE  | STAT
 1   |  A1    | CO
 2   |  A1    | CO
 1   |  B1    | DR
 2   |  B2    | CO
 1   |  C1    | CO
 1   |  C1    | CO
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `Union all`

```
SELECT PO_ID AS ID, PO_TYPE AS TYPE, PO_STAT AS STAT FROM TABLE
UNION ALL 
SELECT MR_ID AS ID, MR_TYPE AS TYPE, MR_STAT AS STAT FROM TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT IN_ID AS ID, IN_TYPE AS TYPE, IN_STAT AS STAT FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
 select PO_ID as ID,PO_TYPE as TYPE,PO_STAT as STAT from table
    union all
 select MR_ID,MR_TYPE,MR_STAT from table

.... and so on
```

Comment: In addition to this answer. Rename the column names.

`select PO_ID AS ID,PO_TYPE AS TYPE,PO_STAT AS STAT from table`